# How to fix low LED light?

Tags: led, soldering, testing

I've connected my LED to 1K resistor. When I tested it out on a breadboard it worked fine, the LED was very bright. Now, when I soldered it to the board, the LED light is poor. I did everything the same, so it confuses me what it could be. Everything else works fine, so that means the connection is good. Could the problem be in the tin or paste I use? Does anyone have an idea?

Edit: The voltage is 5V. I am using the same USB programmer.

Comment: Any normal solder applied in the normal way should have zero influence on how bright the LED is.  What voltage did you use on the breadboard? What voltage did you use on the circuit board?  Did you maybe heat the LED for a very long time at high temperature while soldering?

Comment: Picture of your board?

Comment: Did you use electronic grade solder and flux, or plumbing solder?

Comment: Is Led and resistor the only components on board? Did you use the same power supply? Didnt you solder too long to posiible damage these components? Cannot be a little short on PCB? Didn`t you use the solder filled with some special substance like acids, this fillings have smaller resistance, so it can affect the currents?

Comment: use your volt meter and measure the voltage at each point, you will find it. Do the same with your prototype they should be the same.